# Importar funciones del CDN en react y usarlas en los componentes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy implementando un medio de pago con braintree para devolver un nonunce y enviarlo al backend, en la documentación se explica importa unos cdns propios de ellos, pero toda la explicación está en javascript y yo uso typescript. intenté usar la libería 'react-async-script-loader' para cargar los js y no me lee el metodo braintree. Como hago para que me lea la función que está en los cdn acá en mi proyecto?

```
    class GooglePay extends Component {

      pay() {

        var button = document.querySelector("#google-pay-button");
        var paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
            environment: "TEST", // Or 'PRODUCTION'
        });

        // aca saca el error por que no lee la función braintree que está en el cdn
        braintree.client.create(
        {
            authorization: "",
        },
        function (clientErr, clientInstance) {

            braintree.googlePayment.create(
            {
                client: clientInstance,
                googlePayVersion: 2,
                googleMerchantId: "merchant-id-from-google", // Optional in sandbox; if set in sandbox, this value must be a valid production Google Merchant ID
            },
            )
        })
    }
}
```

estos son los cdns:

```
  'https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"',
  'https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.81.0/js/client.min.js',
  'https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.81.0/js/google-payment.min.js'
```

La imagen es ilustrativa para mostrar el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código como texto no como imagen.

Comment: @AndresGardiol está de las dos formas, la imagen es ilustrativa para mostrar donde está el error

Comment: Por favor aclaralo en la pregunta, si no no se entiende muy bien. Saludos

Comment: ¿La app usa `create-react-app`? ¿O la configuraste de forma manual? Saludos

Comment: si la idea es usarlo de forma global en varios componentes, quizá lo suyo sería mejor intalar la dependencia por npm, sino intenta pasar los scripts al index.js del proyecto.